# i can't access the id column of my table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

i am trying to access the id column of one of my table but i get "**Undefined property**" error but i can access the other columns with no problems,here is my code
in the controller i get all records as follows

```
        $employees=Employee::all();
    return View::make('admin.employee',compact('tittle','heading','employees'));
```

and i my view

```
 @foreach($employees as $employee)
            <tr class="success">
                <td><a href="">{{$employee->first_name}}</a></td>
                <td>{{$employee->last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$employee->phone}}</td>
                <td>{{$employee->salary}}</td>
                <td>{{$employee->created_at}}</td>
                <td><a href="{{URL::route('employee.view',array($employee->id))}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Resign</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">View</a></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

How can i access the id column from my table?
when i print_r($employees);

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => Employee Object ( [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => profile_photo_id [1] => first_name [2] => last_name [3] => gender [4] => phone [5] => address [6] => age [7] => salary ) [connection:protected] => [table:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [timestamps] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 4 [profile_photo_id] => 4 [first_name] => Jason [last_name] => cbvc [gender] => Female [phone] => 2147483647 [address] => jhjhjh [age] => 12 [salary] => 5566556 [created_at] => 2014-12-20 11:29:41 [updated_at] => 2014-12-20 11:29:41 ) [original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 4 [profile_photo_id] => 4 [first_name] => Jason [last_name] => cbvc [gender] => Female [phone] => 2147483647 [address] => jhjhjh [age] => 12 [salary] => 5566556 [created_at] => 2014-12-20 11:29:41 [updated_at] => 2014-12-20 11:29:41 ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [with:protected] => Array ( ) [morphClass:protected] => [exists] => 1 ) [1] => Employee Object ( [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => profile_photo_id [1] => first_name [2] => last_name [3] => gender [4] => phone [5] => address [6] => age [7] => salary ) [connection:protected] => [table:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [timestamps] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 5 [profile_photo_id] => 5 [first_name] => gugu [last_name] => cbvc [gender] => Female [phone] => 2147483647 [address] => jhjhjh [age] => 12 [salary] => 5566556 [created_at] => 2014-12-20 11:40:44 [updated_at] => 2014-12-20 11:40:44 ) [original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 5 [profile_photo_id] => 5 [first_name] => gugu [last_name] => cbvc [gender] => Female [phone] => 2147483647 [address] => jhjhjh [age] => 12 [salary] => 5566556 [created_at] => 2014-12-20 11:40:44 [updated_at] => 2014-12-20 11:40:44 ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [with:protected] => Array ( ) [morphClass:protected] => [exists] => 1 ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give us your **$employees** object , edit question with

```
print_r($employees).
```

Also there may be a chance the **$id** is protected, in that case use.

```
$employee->getOriginal('id');
```